# Excel VBA - Cell(#,#) with variables

Tags: vba, variables, excel, cells

Im wondering if its possible to enter a variable that refers to a range into a Cell objects parameters. ie:

```
Dim visibleRows As Range
Dim visibleColumns As Range

Set visibleColumns = (G:P)
Set visibleRows = (10:20)

Cells(visibleRows, visibleColumns).Formula = "enter formula here"
```

I want to do this because the ranges within each of those variables will change based on parameters in the spreadsheet. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
Dim visibleRows As Range
Dim visibleColumns As Range

Set visibleColumns = Range("G:P")
Set visibleRows = Range("10:20")

Dim r As Range
Set r = Application.Intersect(visibleRows, visibleColumns)
r.Formula = "enter formula here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the `Range` object and refer to the top left corner and bottom right corner. For instance:

```
Range("G10", "P20").Formula = "enter formula here"
```